# javascript:document.forms[0].submit() does not work with IE10

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, post, postback

My Code:

```
<form method="post" action="PreDischargeEducation.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/lots of stuff here" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBgKblbSKDQLWxZaxDwK+n5yTDgKN97n9CAL1m+DgCwKZseiDBoE7ceDrS0JTSg/qHRKRiCdcZ+nF2M69ovt+U0TvDhOh" />
</div>
```

Then at the bottom I have

```
<a class="box" href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">Submit &amp; Continue...</a>
```

However, the button does not go. Is the forms[0] not usable in IE10?

Also, when I use the Return key in the field to submit, the data does not seem to be going to the backend ASP.NET code. Is my JavaScript bad? Works fine in other browsers.

EDIT: The  tag is after the  in the real code.

Comment: where is `form` tag closed?

Comment: one suggested could be to move the script after the `form` is closed

Comment: I did not enclose the </form> but it is way after the </a>

Comment: I was just saying I did not enclose it in the code above but in the real code it is there.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting anything at the backend? Try to output the POST data

Comment: Any error in the console? also in the developer toolbar console try `document.forms[0].submit()`

Comment: FYI if you are using this `document.forms['form1'];` then you need to add the name attribute to the form tag, `name="form1"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this nightmare of a problem by wrapping a jQuery form submit in a setTimeout:

```
$('#complete_profile input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#complete_profile form').submit();
  }, 0);
});
```

This may cause duplicate submission when the form DOES submit, however, so be careful.